# Alternate topping up two capacitor banks

Tags: circuit-design, low-power

I've implemented a [Beam robotics 'solar engine'](http://solarbotics.net/library/circuits/se_t1_micropwr.html) as detailed in the diagram below

[image: Solar engine schematic]

This engine takes a small trickle charge from the solar panel, before discharging the capacitor in one pulse of power. It then starts charging again.

I'd like to power multiple sets of these circuits from one solar bank. The problem I found is that whichever circuit discharges first discharges all the capacitors for all engines. Putting in a diode in the charge lines for each engine results in the engine that discharges first 'short circuiting' the rest of the engines - it essentially takes all the charge from the bank as it cycles whilst the other engines are just below their trigger thresholds.

Does anyone have any suggestions? The simpler the better and preferably very low voltage drop.

Comment: Do each have their own storage capacitor?

Comment: @rdtsc Yes, C1 in the schematic

Comment: One thing I did consider is that its possible to get flashing LEDs, you can potentially use that to pulse charge one engine whilst allowing some charge to go to the other when it is off. If there is a non-light-emitting equivelent i.e. just a pulsing diode with the 0.2V voltage drop that would be a good way forward ...

Comment: Easiest solution is to trigger all motors at the same time.